# How to capture a window using the command line

Tags: osx-lion, command-line-interface, screen-capture

The `screencapture` command doesn't seem to be able to capture a specific window when it is invoked from the command line, but is able to do it when it is used interactively whit shift+command+4.

How can I capture a window from a script ?

Answer (score 0):

```
screencapture -w yourfile.png
```

However the window selection itself is still interactive.

Answer (score 0):

$ screencapture -l #windowId capture.png